# Finding all neighbors within a fixed distance in another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lookup

I am trying to figure out the fastest way to find all neighbors with a fixed distance in another Dataframe.

To better illustrate my question, I have made a hypothetical example. Suppose there are two dataframe `order_df` and `trade_df`, each have two columns - one is ID and another one is datetime.

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd

order_dict = {
    'Order ID': ['Order 1', 'Order 2', 'Order 3', 'Order 4'],
    'Order Time': [datetime.datetime(2023, 3, 8, 7, 5, 0), datetime.datetime(2023, 3, 8, 7, 10, 0), datetime.datetime(2023, 3, 8, 7, 15, 0), datetime.datetime(2023, 3, 8, 7, 20, 0)]
}

trade_dict = {
    'Trade ID': ['Trade 1001', 'Trade 1002', 'Trade 1003', 'Trade 1004', 'Trade 1005'],
    'Trade Time': [datetime.datetime(2023, 3, 8, 7, 8, 0), datetime.datetime(2023, 3, 8, 7, 9, 0), datetime.datetime(2023, 3, 8, 7, 17, 0), datetime.datetime(2023, 3, 8, 7, 18, 0), datetime.datetime(2023, 3, 8, 7, 30, 0)]
}
```

What I expect is: for each row in `order_df`, I look for all `Trade ID`  in `trade_df` with `Trade Time` is within an arbitrary minutes (e.g. 3 mins) before or after `Order Time`

E.g. when the fixed distance = 3 mins, I would expect the output to be:

```
    Order ID    Order Time  Nearest Trade ID
0   Order 1 2023-03-08 07:05:00 Trade 1001
1   Order 2 2023-03-08 07:10:00 Trade 1001, Trade 1002
2   Order 3 2023-03-08 07:15:00 Trade 1003, Trade 1004
3   Order 4 2023-03-08 07:20:00 Trade 1003, Trade 1004
```

I have made the following attempt:

```
def fixed_distance_nearest_neighbors(x, fixed_distance, lookup_df, lookup_field, return_field):
    return ', '.join(lookup_df[lookup_df[lookup_field].between(x - datetime.timedelta(minutes=fixed_distance), x + datetime.timedelta(minutes=fixed_distance))][return_field])

order_df['Nearest Trade ID'] = order_df['Order Time'].apply(lambda x: fixed_distance_nearest_neighbors(x, 3, trade_df, 'Trade Time', 'Trade ID'))
```

However, I believe this is not an efficient way to do this. To be specific, when the size of `order_df` and `trade_df` grows to a large number, the above method is extremely slow, e.g.

```
import random
import time

def generate_random_date(n):
    random_date = []
    for i in range(0, n):
        random_date.append(datetime.datetime(2023, 3, 8, random.randint(0, 23), random.randint(0, 59), random.randint(0, 59)))
    return random_date

n = 100000
order_dict = {
    'Order ID': ['Order ' + str(x) for x in range(1, n + 1)],
    'Order Time': generate_random_date(n)
}

trade_dict = {
    'Trade ID': ['Trade ' + str(x) for x in range(1, n + 1)],
    'Trade Time': generate_random_date(n)
}

start = time.time()
order_df['Nearest Trade ID'] = order_df['Order Time'].apply(lambda x: fixed_distance_nearest_neighbors(x, 3, trade_df, 'Trade Time', 'Trade ID'))
end = time.time()
print(end - start)

#Output 214.34553575515747
```

It takes 3.5 mins to complete the execution. I believe there is some more pythonic way to boost the speed. Thank you very much.

Comment: If `trade_df` is ordered by increasing time you can (1) create new columns in `order_df` with 3 (or whatever) minutes before and after the order time to have the interesting time limits for each order, then (2) use method `searchsorted` to find the start and end location of the related trades for each order, (3) use `apply` or other ways to create the strings with the lists of trade ids.

Comment: I have tried to implement your idea and the execution time is reduced significantly (using the same set of random data, of course), thanks so much!
May I also know what makes such a huge difference in the execution time please? What is the key weakness of my code? Thanks in advance.

Comment: (1) Try to avoid loops over a frame in Python code as well as the `apply` method which nearly does the same. Let pandas do the most work using its internal loops compiled to machine code. (2) Analyze your problem. Here you have or can easily generate a sorted trades frame where you only need for each order a continuous slice of the trades, therefore finding start and end of this slice is enough. (3) Know basic algorithms and data structure. Here: In a sorted sequence, an item can be found very fast with the bisection method (what `searchsorted` does).

Comment: What are a typical number of trades associated with a order? Your example has a huge amount of trades for a single order, which slows things down.

Comment: @WillemHendriks Unfortunately I don't have any idea about the typical number in my mind. It can be a few but it can also be huge, therefore achieving a reasonable speed robust to the number of associated trades is a key requirement of the code.

Comment: Any method will suffer from large associated traders - I guess benchmarking is the only way to find out which methods is best for you. Its good to keep in mind when comparing different methods.

Answer (score 2):

The Following makes use of the [BallTree](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.BallTree.html).

The 10.000 generated order/trade example you used is processed in about 5 seconds. The reasons why its 'slow' is because many trade/order pairs collide. If the date ranges are more spread, and only a handful of trades are associated with a order it is faster.

I only show the example for the toy example. The exact same code was used to test for the larger instance.

With `order_dict` and `trade_dict` , I used the following to convert to unix time;

```
order = pd.DataFrame(order_dict)
trade = pd.DataFrame(trade_dict)

order["unix_time"] = (order["Order Time"] - pd.Timestamp("1970-01-01")) // pd.Timedelta('1s')
trade["unix_time"] = (trade["Trade Time"] - pd.Timestamp("1970-01-01")) // pd.Timedelta('1s')
```

We prepare the data for the tree with;

```
from sklearn.neighbors import BallTree
import numpy as np

order_times = np.expand_dims( order.unix_time.values, axis=1 )
trade_times = np.expand_dims( trade.unix_time.values, axis=1 )
```

...and create and query our tree with;

```
tree = BallTree(trade_times, leaf_size=15, metric="manhattan")
idx, distance_in_seconds = tree.query_radius( order_times, r=60*3, sort_results=True, return_distance=True)
```

The above operation is the actual trade/order linking, and took about 5 seconds for 10.000 trades/orders.Building the tree also takes time. So if you know you are going to repeat this operation, try not rebuild the tree if not needed.

- Note we used [Manhattan](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.DistanceMetric.html) distance, for absolute time in seconds a trade can be away from a order
- From [query_radius()](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.BallTree.html#sklearn.neighbors.BallTree.query_radius), we used `sort_results=True, return_distance=True` to make sure our output is ordered. i.e. The closest trade/order is first.
- Note the `radius` is `60*3` seconds.

```
order["Nearest Trades"] = idx
```

Will give us

```
  Order ID          Order Time   unix_time Nearest Trades
0  Order 1 2023-03-08 07:05:00  1678259100            [0]
1  Order 2 2023-03-08 07:10:00  1678259400         [1, 0]
2  Order 3 2023-03-08 07:15:00  1678259700         [2, 3]
3  Order 4 2023-03-08 07:20:00  1678260000         [3, 2]
```

Notice that for `Order 2`, the closest trade is trade `1`, right after trade `0`. Getting the exact names becomes a heavy operation for larger instances, so I would use indici instead of names.

You also have `distance_in_seconds` which returns the distance in seconds. It has the same shape as `idx` but instead of the index, it contains the distance in seconds for its corresponding index.

Comment: I am trying to digest it. One question coming to my mind is how the number `15` is derived in the `leaf_size` parameter of `BallTree` . May you please explain this more? Thank you.

Comment: A BallTree will create a Tree where all your trade times are. leaf_size is a property where the algorithm will switch from the Tree traversal to brute force. It has (minor) effect on performance, and typical values are around 10~100. If you want to sqeeze out last few seconds in performance, tweak the leaf_size

Comment: @WillemHendriks. I already used many times BallTree (or KDTree) to find nearest points with euclidean distances but I never thought to use it with manhattan distance to find nearest time. So brilliant (much more than my answer :-)) +1

Comment: thx! Its indeed such a flat and 1-dimensional case its a little uncommon. But the math works! :D

Answer (score 1):

You can use `how='cross'` as parameter of `merge` (if your dataframes are not too large):

```
trades = (order_df.merge(trade_df, how='cross')
                  .loc[lambda x: x['Order Time'].sub(x['Trade Time']).abs().lt('3min')]
                  .groupby('Order ID')['Trade ID'].agg(', '.join))

order_df['Nearest Trade'] = order_df['Order ID'].map(trades).fillna('')
```

Output:

```
>>> order_df
  Order ID          Order Time           Nearest Trade
0  Order 1 2023-03-08 07:05:00                        
1  Order 2 2023-03-08 07:10:00  Trade 1001, Trade 1002
2  Order 3 2023-03-08 07:15:00              Trade 1003
3  Order 4 2023-03-08 07:20:00              Trade 1004
```

Comment: Thanks! Using how='cross' as a parameter of 'merge' is a new thing for me!
However just as you have mentioned, this only works when the dataframes are not too large. For n = 100000, this approach does not work unfortunately